# Always showing error message on the form with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm facing this problem how to fix this issue?

This is my problem, always showing an error message:

[image]

This is my model:

```
validates :first_name, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
validates :last_name, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, format: { with: /\A[^@\s]+@([^@.\s]+\.)+[^@.\s]+\z/ }
# validates :passkey, :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
validates_length_of :passkey, :presence => true, :in => 6..20, :on => :register
```

This is my Controller:

```
def register
  params.permit!
  @jobseekers = Jobseeker.new(params[:jobseekers])

  if @jobseekers.save
    redirect_to home_path
  else
    render "register"
  end
end
```

This is my view:

```
<%= form_for :jobseekers, url: register_path(@jobseekers), method: :patch  do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: 'First Name'%>

    <%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: 'Last Name'%>

    <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Email'%>

    <%= f.password_field :passkey, placeholder: 'Password'%>

    <%= f.submit "Create Account" %>

<% end %>

  <% if @jobseekers.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@jobseekers.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
      <% @jobseekers.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I need show this error after click `submit` button, but now showing this error always.

Please help!

Now I'm using `ruby 1.9.7` `rails 4.2.5` & `mysql2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is the controller action:

```
def register
  params.permit!
  @jobseekers = Jobseeker.new(params[:jobseekers])

  if @jobseekers.save
    redirect_to home_path
  else
    render "register"
  end
end
```

if you take a look, then you don't just create a new object `@jobseekers` but try to save it right away. `if @jobseekers.save` will be `false` because the `params[:jobseekers]` is empty when you call the action for the first time. Since you have validations, it will automatically add errors, and your `register` view will be rendered with those errors. This is why usually there are 2 actions with forms- `new` and `create`.

To fix this split this into two actions

```
def register
  @jobseekers = Jobseeker.new
end

def create_register
  params.permit!
  @jobseekers = Jobseeker.new(params[:jobseekers])

  if @jobseekers.save
    redirect_to home_path
  else
    render "register"
  end
end
```

where `create_register` only has a `post` route and `register` has a `get` route (`register` will render the form for the first time, and then after `submit` the `create_register` will be called and render the form with errors if there are any)

This would then be your view(stating the method is not necessary in this case):

```
<%= form_for :jobseekers, url: create_register_path(@jobseekers) do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: 'First Name'%>

    <%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: 'Last Name'%>

    <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Email'%>

    <%= f.password_field :passkey, placeholder: 'Password'%>

    <%= f.submit "Create Account" %>

<% end %>

  <% if @jobseekers.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@jobseekers.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
      <% @jobseekers.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and your `routes.rb` entries:

```
get '/register', to: "jobseekers#register"
post '/register', to: "jobseekers#create_register"
```

Comment: Thanks **Kkulikovskis**  :)

Answer (score 1):

Another take on Kkulikovskis' answer would be:

```
def register
  params.permit!
  @jobseekers = Jobseeker.new(params[:jobseekers])
  return true if request.get? # <--- skip validations if not on form submit

  if @jobseekers.save
    redirect_to home_path
  else
    render "register"
  end
end
```

I prefer this approach when the instantiation of `@jobseeker` is less trivial

PS `params.permit!` is a path to hell, don't do it

Comment: good call. didn't notice that. @ShabbirAhmed , you should white-list your params with a private method instead of allowing mass assignment